# Convert an xml(with a json) to a json response using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a request xml which has a json ->  which I want to map into another json using xslt. I am using xslt 1.0. Is there a way  i can achieve this in xslt 1.0:
The request xml is:

`<root> { "id": 5656, "country-name": "country-text" } <root>`

the response that i need to map to:

`{ "mid": 5656, "cid" : "country-text" }`

Please assist

I tried a few methods, was able to copy the source json into the final response - but that does not help as i need to read individual fields and map them to different keys

With the method i tried -> i was able to get
`{id:5656, country-name:'country-text' }`

what i want is :

`{ mid: 5656, cid : 'country-text' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text>{ mid: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&quot;id&quot;: '), ',')" />
    <xsl:text>, cid : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&quot;country-name&quot;: '), ' }')" />
    <xsl:text> }</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that `country-name` is always the last pair in the JSON object, and `id` is not.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k

my request json is : `<root> { "id": 5656, "country-name": "country-text" } <r/oot>`.  (i hv also edited the question)

I am not getting the values with the above input json

Comment: @MohilM You should not make changes to your question after it has been answered. I have adjusted my answer to work with your modified input. You could have done the same thing, if you had taken the time to understand how it works.

Comment: Thankyou this solution was perfect. Appreciate your time and help :)